# Computing this very long Jquery Statement 

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

```
   <table id="tb1" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" class="formTable" width="100%">
   <tbody>
      <tr> 
         <th class="coltextleft" colspan=3> seats </th>
         <th>Total Seat Count :  <span id="seats">0</span></th>
         <th>SALC  <input name="txt1" type="text" id = "txt1"></th>
         <th>Column name </th>   <th> <input name="id_reset" type="button"  id="id_reset" value="RESET" ></th>              
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td id="zxx"> Col1</td>
         <td> Col2</td>
         <td> Col3</td>
         <td> COL4</td>
         <td>COL5</td>
         <td>COL6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr id ="rnum_$i"><td>$i</td>
         <td><input type="text" id="id_seats$i" name="seats[]"/></td>
         <td>HTML ELEMENT OF TYPE SELECT </td>
         <td>HTML ELEMENT OF TYPE TEXT</td>
         <td>HTML ELEMENT OF TYPE TEXT</td>
         <td>HTML ELEMENT OF TYPE TEXT</td>
         <td>HTML ELEMENT OF TYPE TEXT</td>
      <tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Say for the above html table i have 5 rows and we have a button  "Addone row " which adds up a new row  to the table .

```
var num = $('#id_seats1').parent().parent().parent().children().last().children().html()*1;
```

How do i compute the above  Jquery Statement  for the above html table . The out put that this statement gives the number of rows of 
that are present in the above html table . Can you please show step by step execution of this statement

```
var num = $('#id_seats1').parent().parent().parent().children().last().children().html()*1;
```

Please Help

Comment: why don't you just count the number of rows and subtract the no. of rows that act as header (2 in this case)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 $('#id_seats1')
```

This selects the `<input id='id_seats1'>` element.

```
 .parent().parent().parent()
```

this selects the `td`, then the `tr`, then the `tbody` element.

```
.children().last()
```

this selects the last child of the tbody element, which is a `tr`

```
.children().html()
```

this selects the html contents of all the `td`s in that last row

```
*1
```

this converts the content of the last row (which is a string that contains all the contents of the cells in that row) into a number.

Since the first cell contains a counter `$i` variable, that is the value that winds up being assigned to `var num`

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery statement will not return the number of rows in the table but the content of the last element's children's html's numerical equivalent.

The jQuery snippet to find the total number of rows in the table should've been,

```
var num = $('#id_seats1').parent().parent().parent().children().length - 2;
```

and can be optimized as,

```
var num = $('#id_seats1').closest('tbody').children().length - 2;
```

But the ideal solution would be,

```
var num = $('#tb1 > tbody > tr').length - 2;
```

Comment: @Livinston; I have  various ideas suchas $("#tbl1").attr('rows').length-2 would also gives the number of rows in the "tbl1". But looking to see the advantage of this above?